# KivyMD /MDFileManager: How two get two different URL?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

**GOAL:**

I'd like to use the MDFileManager in KivyMD, in order to get the URL1 and diplay it in the Label1 and then get the URL2 and diplay it in the Label2. I need therefore two buttons and two labels.

**PROBLEM:**

At the moment, the code below is working only for the Button1("Get Url 1") that updates the Label1 (giving to it the URL1).

I need to do exactly the same with the Button2("Get Url 2") that should update the Label2 (giving to it the URL2). Could you guys help in order to achieve it?

Here the code:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.toast import toast


KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDFileManager"
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: None]]
        elevation: 10


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        padding:20

        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Get Url 1"
            icon: "folder"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
            on_release: app.file_manager_open()
            
        MDLabel:
            id: my_custom_label1
            text: "URL 1"
            halign: 'center'   
            
        MDSeparator:
            
        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Get Url 2"
            icon: "folder"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
            on_release: app.file_manager_open()
            
        MDLabel:
            id: my_custom_label2
            text: "URL 2"
            halign: 'center'   
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
            select_path=self.select_path,
            #previous=True,
        )
        self.file_manager.ext = [".xlsx", ".kv"]

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def file_manager_open(self):
        self.file_manager.show('/')  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True

    def select_path(self, path):
        '''It will be called when you click on the file name
        or the catalog selection button.

        :type path: str;
        :param path: path to the selected directory or file;
        '''

        self.exit_manager()
        toast(path)
        self.root.ids.my_custom_label1.text = path


    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        '''Called when the user reaches the root of the directory tree.'''

        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        '''Called when buttons are pressed on the mobile device.'''

        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the id of the label in the button callback, for example: **on_release: app.file_manager_open(my_custom_label1)**, and in the function callback add a variable to the APP class to keep a copy: **self.label_id = label_id**, to use it when the select_path callback is executed, **self.label_id.text = path**

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.toast import toast


KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDFileManager"
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: None]]
        elevation: 10


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        padding:20

        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Get Url 1"
            icon: "folder"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
            on_release: app.file_manager_open(my_custom_label1)
            
        MDLabel:
            id: my_custom_label1
            text: "URL 1"
            halign: 'center'   
            
        MDSeparator:
            
        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: "Get Url 2"
            icon: "folder"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
            on_release: app.file_manager_open(my_custom_label2)
            
        MDLabel:
            id: my_custom_label2
            text: "URL 2"
            halign: 'center'   
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager,
            select_path=self.select_path,
            #previous=True,
        )
        self.file_manager.ext = [".xlsx", ".kv"]

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def file_manager_open(self, label_id):
        self.file_manager.show('/')  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True
        self.label_id = label_id

    def select_path(self, path):
        '''It will be called when you click on the file name
        or the catalog selection button.

        :type path: str;
        :param path: path to the selected directory or file;
        '''
        self.label_id.text = path
        self.exit_manager()
        toast(path)
        
        #self.root.ids.my_custom_label1.text = path


    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        '''Called when the user reaches the root of the directory tree.'''

        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        '''Called when buttons are pressed on the mobile device.'''

        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True


Example().run()
```